# Python loop improvements

Tags: python, loops

I am wondering how efficiently to calculate the distribution of words on array based on the words from another array.

We are given the array of words `test` the task is to aggregate the occurrences of words from `test` in new array `s`

```
for word in test:
    if word not in s:
        mydict[s.count(word)] = 0
    else:           
        mydict[s.count(word)] += 1
```

This code is very slow, partially due to the lack of performance improvements and due to very slow Python's nature in itetations.

What is the best way to improve the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You repeat count iteration for every word in test, adding overhead of word lookup with `if word not in s`. Improvement might be in calculating counts once:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(s)
```

then getting hystogram in second pass:

```
distribution = Counter(counts[v] for v in set(test))
```

Demo:

```
>>> test = list('abcdef')
>>> s = list('here comes the sun')
>>> counts = Counter(s)
>>> distribution = Counter(counts[v] for v in set(test))
>>> distribution
Counter({0: 4, 1: 1, 4: 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Counter` and that is what they are for

```
from collections import Counter
print Counter(Counter(test).values())
```

For example,

```
test = ["the", "sun", "rises", "in", "the", "sun"]
from collections import Counter
print Counter(test)
print Counter(Counter(test).values())
```

**Output**

```
Counter({'sun': 2, 'the': 2, 'rises': 1, 'in': 1})
Counter({1: 2, 2: 2})
```